# AuthenticationAbandoned: Overridden by new authentication session

Tags: mongodb, replicaset, mongodb-replica-set

What does this log mean? I have a replicaset with 3 nodes and this is the line from primary where every php script connects. It repeats constantly every N seconds.

```
{"t":{"$date":"2024-03-21T11:36:32.199+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":5286307, "ctx":"conn3170","msg":"Failed to authenticate","attr":{"client":"a.b.c.d:53548","isSpeculative":false,"isClusterMember"
:false,"mechanism":"","user":"","db":"","error":"AuthenticationAbandoned: Overridden by new authentication session","result":337,"metrics":{"conversation_duration":{"micros":60605965,"summary":{}}},"extraInfo":{}}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found that this is a [bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CDRIVER-4812).
Discussion is [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/1506#issuecomment-1885224768).